# How to drop duplicates between two columns, but keep unique values in respective columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this;

```
col1     col2  
aa       aa
cc       bb
dd       dd
```

How do I compare both columns in the same df but drop the duplicates and keep the unique in their respective columns?

new df:

```
col1     col2  
cc       bb
```

Comment: So you want the rows where the value of `col1` is *not* equal to the corresponding one in `col2`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df[df[col1] != df[col2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can construct a filter that checks if the value of `df.col1` is different from `df.col2`, and then filter, like:

```
df[df.col1 != df.col2]
```

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['aa', 'aa'], ['cc', 'bb'], ['dd', 'dd']], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
>>> df
  col1 col2
0   aa   aa
1   cc   bb
2   dd   dd
>>> df[df.col1 != df.col2]
  col1 col2
1   cc   bb
```

We here construct a *new* dataframe, but we can thus set `df` to the new dataframe, like:

```
df = df[df.col1 != df.col2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the rows that have the same value across columns, this should do.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'a':[40, 30, 10],
       'b':[40, 20, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[~(df['a']==df['b'])]
```

Output

```
>>> df
    a   b
0  10  40
2  30  10
```